# Sort Objects in 2nd level array

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to sort this. Below is a sample of my array.

```
product_sort_arr = [
  [{name:'Particle'},link:value}],
  [{name:'Bio-Part112',link:value}],
  [],
  etc  . . . 
];
```

I hope you can visualize the sample.

so far I have tried using and it's still not working. Still trying to fix this. Any help would be great

```
product_sort_arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name - b.name;
})
```

Expected return

```
product_sort_arr = [
  [{name:'Bio-Part112'},link:value}],
  [{name:'Particle',link:value}],
  [],
  etc  . . . 
];
```

Comment: array is not symmetric. please write the exepected array

Comment: What are you expecting when you are making math operation (minus) on strings? Actually it's NaN. You need something else to compare with. Also, in sort function, `a` and `b` are arrays and they don't have `name`.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267329/how-to-sort-a-js-object-literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your array should be, but now it is defined with some errors. This example is working. I hope it will move you in the right direction.

```
var product_sort_arr = [
  [{name:'Particle', link:'value'}],
    [{name:'Bio-Part112',link:'value'}],
];

product_sort_arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[0].name > b[0].name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a[0].name < b[0].name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
    for (i=0;i<product_sort_arr.length;i++) {
        console.log(product_sort_arr[i][0].name);
}
```

Check on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwspt1L2/1/)

Note that the array is an array of objects so you get the name with `product_sort_arr[0][0].name` and `product_sort_arr[1][0].name`

Comment: Completed the answer with the input of Naomik.

Comment: Working now, Thanks for the help and the other peeps. Main problem was the comparison of the strings thing.

Answer (score 0):

your array is not symmetric, i have created this demo it will sort the array based on `name`

```
var p = [
  [{name:'Particle',link:'valueA'}],
  [{name:'Bio-Part112',link:'valueB'}],
];
console.log(p);
p.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[0].name > b[0].name;
});
console.log(p);
```